# "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a website with an ML model using Flask and Python.

I keep getting this error when I input the values to get the prediction

> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not
> understand.

Here is the code I have written so far.

This is the app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))  # loading the model

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    """Grabs the input values and uses them to make prediction"""
    # rooms = int(request.form["rooms"])
    # distance = int(request.form["distance"])

    radius_mean  =  int(request.form["radius_mean"])
    texture_mean=   int(request.form["texture_mean"])
    perimeter_mean= int(request.form["perimeter_mean"])
    area_mean=  int(request.form["area_mean"])
    smoothness_mean=    int(request.form["smoothness_mean"])
    compactness_mean=   int(request.form["compactness_mean"])
    concavity_mean= int(request.form["concavity_mean"])
    concave_points_mean =   int(request.form["concave_points_mean"])
    symmetry_mean=  int(request.form["symmetry_mean"])
    fractal_dimension_mean= int(request.form["fractal_dimension_mean"])
    radius_se=  int(request.form[radius_se])
    texture_se= int(request.form["texture_se"])
    perimeter_se=   int(request.form["perimeter_se"])
    area_se=    int(request.form["area_se"])
    smoothness_se=  int(request.form["smoothness_se"])
    compactness_se= int(request.form["compactness_se"])
    concavity_se=   int(request.form["concavity_se"])
    concave_points_se=  int(request.form["concave_points_se"])
    symmetry_se=    int(request.form["symmetry_se"])
    fractal_dimension_se=   int(request.form["fractal_dimension_se"])
    radius_worst=   int(request.form["radius_worst"])
    texture_worst=  int(request.form["texture_worst"])
    perimeter_worst=    int(request.form["perimeter_worst"])
    area_worst= int(request.form["area_worst"])
    smoothness_worst=   int(request.form["smoothness_worst"])
    compactness_worst=  int(request.form["compactness_worst"])
    concavity_worst=    int(request.form["concavity_worst"])
    concave_points_worst=   int(request.form["concave_points_worst"])
    symmetry_worst= int(request.form["symmetry_worst"])
    fractal_dimension_worst=    int(request.form["fractal_dimension_worst"])


    prediction = model.predict
    ([[radius_mean, 
    texture_mean, 
    perimeter_mean, 
    area_mean, 
    smoothness_mean, 
    compactness_mean, 
    concavity_mean, 
    concave_points_mean, 
    symmetry_mean, 
    fractal_dimension_mean, 
    radius_se, 
    texture_se, 
    perimeter_se, 
    area_se, 
    smoothness_se, 
    compactness_se, 
    concavity_se, 
    concave_points_se, 
    symmetry_se, 
    fractal_dimension_se, 
    radius_worst, 
    texture_worst, 
    perimeter_worst, 
    area_worst, 
    smoothness_worst, 
    compactness_worst, 
    concavity_worst, 
    concave_points_worst, 
    symmetry_worst,
    fractal_dimension_worst
    ]])  # this returns a list e.g. [127.20488798], so pick first element [0]
    output = round(prediction[0], 30) 

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=f'A tumour with {rooms} {radius_mean}{texture_mean} {perimeter_mean} {area_mean} {smoothness_mean} {compactness_mean} {concavity_mean} {concave_points_mean} {symmetry_mean} {fractal_dimension_mean} {radius_se} {texture_se} {perimeter_se} {area_se} {smoothness_se} {compactness_se} {concavity_se} {concave_points_se} {symmetry_se} {fractal_dimension_se} {radius_worst} {texture_worst} {perimeter_worst} {area_worst} {smoothness_worst} {compactness_worst} {concavity_worst} {concave_points_worst} {symmetry_worst} {fractal_dimension_worst} from the city center has a value of {output}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the index.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <h2>Price Prediction</h2>
          <p>Introduce the number of rooms and distance:</p>
           <!-- Inputs for our ML model -->
            <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
              <input type="text" name="radius_mean  " placeholder="radius_mean " required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="texture_mean" placeholder="texture_mean" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="perimeter_mean" placeholder="perimeter_mean" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="area_mean" placeholder="area_mean" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="smoothness_mean" placeholder="smoothness_mean" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="compactness_mean" placeholder="compactness_mean" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="concavity_mean" placeholder="concavity_mean" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="concave_points_mean" placeholder="concave_points_mean" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="symmetry_mean" placeholder="symmetry_mean" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="fractal_dimension_mean" placeholder="fractal_dimension_mean"required="required"/>

              <input type="text" name="radius_se " placeholder="radius_se " required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="texture_se" placeholder="texture_se" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="perimeter_se" placeholder="perimeter_se"required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="area_se" placeholder="area_se" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="smoothness_se" placeholder="smoothness_se" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="compactness_se" placeholder="compactness_se"  required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="concavity_se" placeholder="concavity_se"  required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="concave_points_se" placeholder="concave_points_se"required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="symmetry_se" placeholder="symmetry_se" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="fractal_dimension_se" placeholder="fractal_dimension_se"required="required"/>

              <input type="text" name="radius_worst" placeholder="radius_worst"required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="texture_worst" placeholder="texture_worst" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="perimeter_worst" placeholder="perimeter_worst" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="area_worst" placeholder="area_worst" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="smoothness_worst" placeholder="smoothness_worst"  required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="compactness_worst" placeholder="compactness_worst" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="concavity_worst" placeholder="concavity_worst" required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="concave_points_worst" placeholder="concave_points_worst" required="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="symmetry_worst" placeholder="symmetry_worst"  required="required" />
              <input type="text" name="fractal_dimension_worst" placeholder="fractal_dimension_worst" required="required"/>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict Value!</button>
            </form>
         
          <br>
          <br>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image attached shows the dataset and the columns present.
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Which specific endpoint were you trying to call? How are you calling it? This type of error is usually caused by wrong way of calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

Flask actually indicates the cause of the error.

- On the browser after clicking on the Predict button
  [image: screenshot of the error on the browser - top half]
  ...
  [image: screenshot of the error on the browser - bottom half]
- On the server-side logs:

  ```
  werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
  KeyError: 'radius_mean'
  ```

The initial problem is that your keys have some extra spaces:

- index.html

  ```html
  <input type="text" name="radius_mean  " .../>
                                      ^
                                      | There are 2 trailing spaces!
  ```
- view function

  ```
  radius_mean  =  int(request.form["radius_mean"])
  ```

The spaces are not automatically stripped, and spaces matter:

```
In [8]: "radius_mean" == "radius_mean  "
Out[8]: False
```

Check all your keys on your HTML and Python code, and make sure they are consistent. The same error will also happen if your view function tries to access a form key that is not in the HTML template.

To help you debug, on your view function, you can check what  `request.form` contains, which is just like a dictionary. You can use your debugger or do `print(request.form.keys())`.

A big improvement you can do here is to define an iterable (ex. list, tuple, etc.) to store all the keys. Pass that iterable to your HTML template, and dynamically generate the form `<input>` for each key, since your example shows they are all just copy-pasted with different `name`'s and `placeholder`'s. Then in your view function, again loop through this same iterable to parse the form.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

FORM_KEYS = (
    "radius_mean",
    "texture_mean",
    "perimeter_mean",
    "area_mean",
    "smoothness_mean",
    # Add the other keys here
)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", form_keys=FORM_KEYS)

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # This is a dictionary comprehension.
    # You can also manually assign the values one-by-one
    form_values = {
        form_key: int(request.form[form_key])
        for form_key in FORM_KEYS
    }  

    model_values = list(form_values.values())
    prediction = model.predict([model_values])
    ...
```

```
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
    {% for form_key in form_keys %}
      <input type="text" name="{{ form_key }}" placeholder="{{ form_key }}" required="required" /> 
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict Value!</button>
</form>
```

That should help prevent inconsistencies in the form keys, and improves the maintainability since you only need to update and check the keys in 1 place.